# Android Studio JVM initialization problems

Tags: java, android, android-studio, jvm

I have seen similar issues but none fixed my problem and mine is different.

My app was working fine but when I went to run it today, I got the error:

```
Error:Unable to start the daemon process.
This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
Please refer to the user guide chapter on the daemon at https://docs.gradle.org/2.10/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
Please read the following process output to find out more:
-----------------------
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for 2097152KB object heap
```

In my gradle.properties I have:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2g
```

In module/build.gradle:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "..."
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
    dexOptions {
        preDexLibraries true
        javaMaxHeapSize "2g"
        incremental true
        dexInProcess = true
    }
}
```

Changing to 1g will allow gradle sync, but upon running it I get:

> Execution failed for task ':mobile:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1"

Changing to 3g gives the cannot reserve space error. 4g gives:

> The specified size exceeds the maximum representable size

And 512m gives the same error has 1g. None of these settings seem to work.

I've tried deleting my Users/user/.gradle folder, invalidating cache and restarting, cleaning and rebuilding project, etc...

Comment: Replace it with this: `org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xms256m -Xmx1024m`

Comment: Going back to the default settings worked, check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up fixing this by removing all references to sdk 24 and using sdk 23. I also removed the jvmargs and dexOptions, taking it back to the default state. It may have been an issue with the preview.

Comment: Mark your answer as the solution, if you can.

Comment: Need to wait 2 days.